# Sums , products, binomialcoefficient Induction

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

To show: $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_0,\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{x}{k}=(-1)^n\binom{x-1}{n}$$
$\underline{Basecase}$

$n=0$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{0}(-1)^k\binom{x}{k}=(-1)^0\binom{x}{0}=1=(-1)^0\binom{x-1}{0}$$

$\underline{Assumption}$

For some $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and a fixed but arbitary $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the following holds:$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{x}{k}=(-1)^n\binom{x-1}{n}$$
$$\iff\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\prod_{i=1}^{k}\frac{x+1-i}{i}=(-1)^{n}\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x-i}{i}$$
$$\iff\sum_{k=0}^{n}\prod_{i=1}^{k}\frac{-x-1+i}{i}=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{-x+i}{i}$$
$$\iff\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{i=1}^{k}(-x-1+i)=\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-x+i)$$
$\underline{Claim}$

For $(n+1)\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and a fixed but arbitary $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the following holds:$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{i=1}^{k}(-x-1+i)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(-x+i)$$
$\underline{Step}$

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ be arbitary but fixed. Let $(n+1)\in\mathbb{N}_0$. We have to show that the equality$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{i=1}^{k}(-x-1+i)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(-x+i)$$ holds.
$$\iff\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(-x-1+i)+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\prod_{i=1}^{k}(-x-1+i)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(-x+i)$$
Now use our assumption to get
$$\iff\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(-x-1+i)+\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-x+i)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}(-x+i)$$
$$\iff\frac{(-x+n)}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-x-1+i)+\frac{1}{n!}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-x+i)=\frac{(-x+n+1)}{(n+1)!}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-x+i)$$
$$\iff\frac{(-x+n)}{(n+1)}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-x-1+i)+\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-x+i)=\frac{(-x+n+1)}{(n+1)}\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-x+i)$$
Im kinda lost at the end. Could you say if this is going into the right direction?

Comment: It's more convenient to not expand the binomial coefficients. Start with $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n+1} (-1)^k \binom{x}{k} = \Biggl(\sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k\binom{x}{k}\Biggr) + (-1)^{n+1}\binom{x}{n+1} = (-1)^n\binom{x-1}{n} + (-1)^{n+1}\binom{x}{n+1} = (-1)^{n+1}\Biggl(\binom{x}{n+1} - \binom{x-1}{n}\Biggr).$$

Comment: @DanielFischer ah, and then we finally use Pascal's triangle. Much better then my try thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both sides are polynomials of degree $n$ in $x$, it suffices to show that the equality holds for $x=1,2, ... , n+1$.  For that, use the fact that the alternating sum of binomial coefficients is 0.

Comment: that doesn't help much because the RHS is not a alternating sum but a binomial times (-1) or 1.

Comment: For $x=1, ..., n$, the LHS is an alternating sum and the RHS is 0. For $x=n+1$, if you move the RHS to the LHS, you do get an alternating sum.

Comment: hi, x is element of the reals. That's why i even started with the $\prod$-Stuff. So x just might be 0.5, which will never be n+1.

Comment: Yes, $x$ is a real number, but $n$ is a nonnegative integer. So, $\binom{x}{n}$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $x$: for example, $\binom{x}{2} = x(x-1)/2$. Then, if two polynomials of degree $n$ agree for $n+1$ distinct values, then they agree for all _real_ values.

Comment: i think i got now your idea. sorry i was just too busy to understand it. thanks for the explanation.